# Do not prompt options on select2 until there has been a keystroke

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using [select2 library](https://select2.github.io/), Right now when I clicked on the select2 input fields it opens the dropdown but I don't want to open the dropdown on click I want to open the select2 options drop-down on keystroke, Any help will be appreciatable.

Here is my code:

```
    share_users_select = $('#sharing-user-email').select2
      tags: true,
      placeholder: 'Enter Email Address',
      selectOnClose: true,
      closeOnSelect: false,
      tokenSeparators: [',', ';', ' '],
      templateSelection: format,
      templateResult: format
      createTag: (term, data) ->
        value = term.term
        if validateEmail(value)
          return {
            id: value
            text: value
          }
        null
    share_users_select.val("").trigger("change")
    share_users_select.on 'select2:unselecting', (e) ->
      $(this).data 'unselecting', true
      disableShareButton()
    share_users_select.on 'select2:opening', (e) ->
      if $(this).data('unselecting')
        $(this).removeData 'unselecting'
        e.preventDefault()
      setTimeout(getEmptyImagesForSelect2, 1500)
    share_users_select.on 'select2:close', (e) ->
      setTimeout(onCloseSelect2SetGravatar, 1000)
    share_users_select.on 'select2:select', (e) ->
      console.log 'select'
      disableShareButton()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your select2 on element, set `minimumInputLength: 1` in the options.

```
$('#sharing-user-email').select2({
    /** 
     * your other options here
     *
     */

     //set minimum input length
     minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a solution and it works as I needed,
Just need to add a condition in 'createTag' function.

```
createTag: (term, data) ->
    value = term.term
    if value
      share_users_select.select2("open")
    else
      share_users_select.select2("close")
```